# Does Markovnikov's Rule apply to reactions like Dehydration of Alcohols?

Tags: organic-chemistry

I understand Markovnikov's rule essentially tells us the major product in addition reactions when a smaller polar molecule is added onto an unsymmetrical larger compound, however does it also apply to the dehydration of alcohols ie not addition reactions?

Or perhaps is there another rule, regardless can you determine the major/minor product?

Comment: You’re looking for Zaitsev's rule